# wordpress opens links in new window - but "target" property not set

Tags: javascript, wordpress, new-window

I am working on http://hocoastl.com/ and am running into a weird issue. When I hover over the options for the links in the nav bar the code looks like this: (replaced < characters with [ for readability)

```
[a href="https://www.hocoastl.com/join-us/"]
[cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="JOIN" style="width: 26px; height: 14px;"]
[canvas width="36" height="15" style="width: 36px; height: 15px; top: -1px; left: -1px;"]
[/canvas]
[cufontext]JOIN[/cufontext]
[/cufon][/a]
```

When I click the link, the page opens in a new window. When I go back to the original window that has the home page and do an "Inspect Element" in Chrome this is what the [a] tag looks like now:

```
[a href="https://www.hocoastl.com/join-us/" target="_blank"]
```

How is the **target="_blank"** getting there? I am so confused, I have never seen this before.

Comment: Probably have a script somewhere in your WP template adding the target before opening the link

Comment: I agree with @Karl-AndréGagnon. Some plugins can cause this to happen as well.

Answer (score 1):

Are there any Javascript `click()` events or listeners on the href? It may be the culprit...

Comment: ah!

Just looked at your page, indeed at the bottom of the page you have a JS event that inserts the target attribute on a click: 

<script>var pltNewTabURLs = ["https:\/\/www.hocoastl.com\/join-us\/","https:\/\/www.hocoastl.com\/hocoa-business-advantage\/","https:\/\/www.hocoastl.com\/contractors\/","http:\/\/www.hocoa.com"];(function(){jQuery(function(e){return e("body") **.on("click","a"**,function(t){var n;n=e(this);if(e.inArray(n.attr("href"),pltNewTabURLs)>-1)return n **.attr("target","_blank")** })})}).call(this);</script>

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a javascript event bound to click events on `a` elements that automatically adds `target="_blank"` when you click on them.

Try searching through your script files for `.click`, `_blank`, `.attr('target')` or similar.